# Is Ann Arbor within reasonable Lyft/Uber range of DTW?

Tags: airport-transfer, ride-sharing, michigan, dtw

My family is going to a wedding in Ann Arbor. From a map, it looks like it's within reason to Lyft or Uber from the DTW airport. (Where "reasonable" means something like "under $50".) Does this make sense or are there any gotchas?

I know this can be calculated with the app (or various online price estimators), but I'd really love to hear from a local or someone else with personal experience.

Comment: Useful to say what day and time of day you plan to arrive and leave. Weekday rush hour? Sunday morning?

Comment: @smci Planning on Friday evening, but could be flexible if that's a big factor — plane tickets aren't bought yet.

Comment: Do taxis not exist any more?

Comment: Not interested in being driven the long way by an aggressive driver who tells me at the end his credit card reader is broken and he needs cash, so, yeah, effectively taxis do not exist.

Comment: Yes, dragging bags halfway across the airport to reach the uber dungeon nobody knows where it is *and has no cell service*, to get an amateur driver chosen at random who texts continuously while driving, and talks incessantly about politics, and doesn't know the way, is so much better...

Comment: I'm not super-interested in having that debate here. However, if you really believe taxis will provide a better experience than ride-hailing services_based on actual experience from DTW to Ann Arbor_, please provide that as an answer.

Comment: If your schedule is flexible, there is a very affordable bus service (AirRide) that will take you downtown. Fairly comfortable and there's even wifi.

Comment: @abought Thanks -- schedule is flexible until booked, but of course won't be so flexible once the flights are determined. It [looks like](https://www.michiganflyer.com/Portals/0/pdf/Ann%20Arbor%20Schedule%20as%20of%20Feb%2010%202020%20v4.pdf?ver=2020-01-29-192825-107) that's a little less than once every hour, so that might be okay. Have you used it before?

Comment: I've used it quite a few times; it's clean and generally works pretty well. They're good about letting you use the next/previous shuttle even with a reservation (space allowing)- that helps smooth out uncertainty when baggage claim or flight delays are involved.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking this instead of just checking the app. It's kind of like asking if the price to fly between two cities is reasonable. Go look at the price and see for yourself. What kind of local/insider knowledge are you hoping for here?

Comment: @Kat Exactly like that in the accepted answer.

Comment: Really? They gave an outdated price which may or may not be accurate, said there is traffic in the morning on weekdays (true everywhere with a decent population, something like Google maps can give you a more specific idea of how bad and where) and the wait was a bit long (true of most airports). Obviously lots of people take ride shares from a major airport to a nearby major city, so I'm not sure what that anecdote gets you.

Comment: @Kat Feel free to provide something better and more up-to-date.

Comment: I usually take the MIchigan Flyer.

Comment: [AirRide to Ann Arbor is $11 each-way per person](https://www.theride.org/Services/Airport-Service/Fares), takes ~50 min, runs every 60-90 min.

Comment: I get useful information like "the app says under $40, but watch out for rush hour where it could be $100", and specific information about the local rush hour. I'm not sure why that upsets some people — *eh, Stack Exchange*, I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I write this answer from a Lyft going from Ann Arbor to DTW.

Booking this ride on Lyft cost $50, whereas it was $100 on Uber with surge pricing. I’ve seen it as low as $35. So yes, for convenience, Uber and Lyft definitely work.

But as other answers mention, there are better options for more like $13/trip.

Answer (score 36):

Both Uber and Lyft apps allow you to enter both a "from" and "to" location that is nowhere near your current location.

Thus you can simple open the app, enter DTW as the pickup location, the location of your wedding as the destination, and it will give you a price for that journey.  This allows you to confirm that taking such a journey is feasible, and roughly how much it will cost - although obviously the cost can vary based on the time of day/traffic/etc.

Looking at the moment, Uber is quoting a little under $40 from DTW to Ann Arbor.

Answer (score 10):

Also consider the Michigan Flyer https://www.michiganflyer.com/

A bus from DTW to Ann Arbor that goes 13x a day.

Comment: Highly recommend this, I did it about a month ago and it was very comfortable

Answer (score 8):

I'm not a local, but a while ago I worked at Ford and lived in Ann Arbor for a time, so I did that commute every day.  Your main gotcha is going to be the state of I-94 (and I-275 as an alternative route).  This can be very bad in rush hour.  If you're arriving in the evening after 7pm, you should usually be safe.

If you're getting a hotel for the weekend, consider that Ann Arbor is not a small area, and it has limited access to I-94 along the west side.  If you want to minimise costs from the airport, then staying somewhere in the south-east or east of the city should make your Uber cheaper. Assuming of course that someone local can give you a ride to the wedding.

Answer (score 4):

Since you said you want personal experience, I have made this trip a few times via Uber while visiting Ann Arbor. It should be reasonable, though my last trip was 2 years ago ($36 at ~8 AM). There can be a large amount of traffic slow down in the morning on a weekday, as Graham's answer indicates.

The pickup time was a bit longer than I was used to, I think it took 10-15 minutes for the driver to arrive at the Airport. I also took an Uber from the hotel to the wedding venue, it is a very common area for weddings so the driver should be familiar with where to take you.

Answer (score 3):

Rent a car for cheap. I was just in Ann Arbor a few months ago. My wife goes all the time. If we are there for only a day, Uber makes sense for a one time round trip from the airport and back. If you are there for more than one day, rent a car. Unless you want to burden family members with schlepping you around, it’s more convenient for everyone. Plus, Ann Arbor is a pretty nice area. And, except for rush hour, the drive is easy. It would be worth the $20-30/day or so as long as you do not have to pay for hotel parking. We usually don’t.